# How to suggest an edit which has less than minimum of "6" characters?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

In [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/what-exactly-is-dehi-according-to-advaita-and-vaishnava-school) question, there was a spelling mistake of hindus ("hindoos) and hence I suggested an edit to change. But the edit was not saved and sent to review queue and it displayed edit must be minimum of "6 characters".

As a result, I [removed the word thanks](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/30111/what-exactly-is-dehi-according-to-advaita-and-vaishnava-school) from the question to edit it!

Thus, when we find 2 or 3 letter spelling mistakes like these, how can we edit the question? Should we flag for moderators intervention those who have less than 1000k?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As discussed at [How to overcome "Edits must be at least 6 characters"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81520/260388):

> Remember, when you suggest an edit, it requires multiple other people to look at it and approve it. The character limit is to prevent people from wasting time by looking at exceptionally minor edits. So, don't limit yourself to just a tiny edit: **try to see if you can improve the post to a possible state of perfection.**

Here you tried to remove remove "Thanks" and that's fine.

"Should we flag for moderators intervention"? [No](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149772/260388). Once you will earn [edit privilege](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) you can make [single character](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/77257/260388) edit! Though it's [discouraged](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit):

> Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged - try to make the post significantly better when you edit, correcting all problems that you observe.

Comment: Yes i understand with respect to minor changes edit! But when words like hindoos are used I think, those words need to be edited right? In a case where there are no other errors in question

Comment: @AkshayKumarS yes, I agree that there are no other options but its the design that we have to accept, see [Are we discouraged from fixing typos and misspellings on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77233/260388)

Answer (score 3):

Leave those edits to users with 1k reputation.

Edits which are less than 6 characters are trivial.

### What can you do when the edit is not even 6 characters?

Try to improve title and the terms present in the question/answer. Edit the tags. Title and tags do not have character limits. Try to improve as much as possible. This will push the edit into review queue.

Do *not* flag the post for moderator intervention. Flags should be only used as a last resort. Post only require serious intervention of moderators should be brought to their attention.